# How to change class of individual elements inside ngfor?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm very sorry if this question has been answered however I was unable to find an appropriate answer. I am attempting to create a simple chat application and wish for messages sent by the current user to appear on the right hand side of the screen whilst messages from other users will appear on the left.

I believe I am most of the way there with this however its not functioning properly, if the most recent message is sent by the current user then all the message will be on the right vica versa for messages from other users.

My question in more detail therefor is, is there a way for me to change the class for a list item that is generated by ngFor, with each element possibly having a different class to any other list item.

Below is the HTML:

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index" (click)="beingWhisper(message)">

    <ion-card [ngClass]="styleClass">
      <ion-card-header class="messageHeader">
        {{i}}{{message.Person}}
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        {{message.Message}}
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-item>
```

Here is the very basic CSS:

```
.message-other{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.message-self{
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

The ngClass variable is controlled simply with this variable on my component class, this is changed to be either "message-self" or "message-other" when required

```
    styleClass = '';
```

**Fixed**: 
In case anyone finds this question with a similar problem, my issue was fixed by using the individual messages property, which held the senders ID and if it was the same as the current user ID then apply the style I wanted, this was discovered through dfsq's suggestion, with thanks to Günter Zöchbauer as his suggestion was also correct

Comment: Please post your code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: I am attempting this now, thank you

Comment: I have added the code that Is anything to do with the issue

Comment: What does it depend on whether `.message-other` or `.message-self` should be added? If it's `message.Person` where does `message` come from and what does `message.Person` contain?

Comment: "The ngClass variable is controlled simply with this variable on my component class" I think that's the main mistake. I think it needs to be controlled by the message, otherwise you only have one value for the whole component.

Comment: In app session you should know what is the current user. `message` object should also contain sender id. Compare two and here you go: `[ngClass]="message.userId === currentUser.id ? 'message-self' : 'message-other'"`

Comment: very sorry for the confusion, the message.person/message are simply text that is displayed, I am attempting to use ngClass to swap between the message-other and message-self classes depending on if the message itself was sent by the current user or other users

Comment: @dfsq your suggestion is exactly what I needed, thank you very much, if you post your comment of changing the [ngClass] snippet to what you suggested as an answer ill be happy to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do in cases like this is to compare currently authenticated used id with message id, which should be a sender used id. Then you ngClass look something like this:

```
[ngClass]="message.userId === currentUser.id ? 'message-self' : 'message-other'"
```